# Query no reconoce variables en Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Al hacer un update en codeigniter, este no reconoce la variable que le estoy pasando.

```
public function actualizaPropiedadModel($tipoPropiedad,$cItem)
{
    $data       = array('tDescripcion' => $tipoPropiedad);
    $this->db->where('iSeqTabla',56);
    $this->db->where('cItem',$cItem);

    $query = $this->db->update('tablaxxx',$data); 

    if($query){ return 1; } else{ return 0; } 
}
```

Si hago echo a $tipoPropiedad o a $cItem, me las muestra bien, el problema surge cuando las meto a la query, me trae los datos en 0

UPDATE tablaxxx SET tDescripcion = 0 WHERE iSeqTabla = 56 AND cItem = 0

Comment: dentro del modelo al realizar un `var_dump` a las variables que recibe, de que tipo son? son del mismo tipo que declaraste en la db?

Comment: String, eso es lo más raro, he hecho cientos de consultas de ese modo, y es la primera vez que me sucede esto.

Comment: que query te imprimie con esto `$this->db->get_where('tablaxxx', array('iSeqTabla' => 56, 'tDescripcion' => $tipoPropiedad))->row();echo $this->db->last_query();` Para validar el primer valor que lo reconozca bien

Comment: Sigue trayendo 0

    SELECT * FROM tablaxxx WHERE iSeqTabla = 56 AND tDescripcion = 0

Comment: lo único que se me ocurre es que no estén llegando bien las variables al modelo

Comment: eso sería lo lógico, que no estén llegando, pero si le hago un echo a las variables dentro del modelo, si las muestra, a donde no están entrando es a la query en si.

Comment: @eddenmedio Bueno te cuento que pude solucionarlo, aunque sinceramente no lo solucioné, derrepente las empezó a reconocer, servidor, jquery, no se...no se que fue pero sin hacer cambios empezó a tomar. 

Agradezco tu ayuda.

Comment: esperemos que todo siga bien en el futuro